# How to call class methods on a background thread using CThreadPool

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, threadpool, atl

Let's say you have some sort of class, and you'd like to call some of its methods on a background thread.  That's what I'm interested in, and I thought [`CThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/cthreadpool-class?view=msvc-160) would be a nice thing to use for this.  I was wondering if anyone has used `CThreadPool` for method calls before.

So here's what I've set up.  Based on [this](https://github.com/microsoft/VCSamples/tree/master/VC2008Samples/ATL/Advanced/CThreadPool) example from Microsoft, I've created an abstract "task" class (which I've denoted as an interface), as well as a worker class:

```
class ITask
{
public:
    virtual void DoTask(LPVOID, LPOVERLAPPED) = 0;
};

class CWorker
{
public:
    typedef DWORD_PTR RequestType;

    BOOL Initialize(LPVOID)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    void Execute(RequestType dw, LPVOID pvParam, LPOVERLAPPED pOverlapped) throw()
    {
        ITask* pTask = (ITask*)(DWORD_PTR)dw;
        pTask->DoTask(pvParam, pOverlapped);
    }

    void Terminate(LPVOID)
    {
    }
};
```

Then in my main class, I essentially do this:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass()
    {
        m_threadpool.Initialize(this, NUM_OF_THREADS_DESIRED);
    }
    ~MyClass()
    {
        m_threadpool.Shutdown();
    }

private:
    CThreadPool<CWorker> m_threadpool;
    
    class : public ITask
    {
    public:
        void DoTask(LPVOID pvParam, LPOVERLAPPED)
        {
            MyClass* pObj = (MyClass*)pvParam;
            pObj->MethodToCallOnBackgroundThread();
        }
    } m_task;

    void MethodForQueuing()
    {
        m_threadpool.QueueRequest((CWorker::RequestType)&m_task);
    }

    void MethodToCallOnBackgroundThread()
    {
        // Do something
    }
};
```

This seems to work.  One drawback is that it requires declaring a new `ITask`-derived class for every method that you'd like to use the threadpool for, but that's apparently how the Microsoft example works.  I guess another approach would be to create a more generic task object and then pass in an enum or something, which can be used for a switch statement within a class method.  Anyway, has anyone dealt with this situation, and if so, do you have any input?

Comment: Unless there's a specific reason you want to write this sort of early-2000s code in an unnecessarily platform-specific way, I'd suggest you either just use `std::async`, or at least package your tasks up into `std::function` objects instead of writing each concrete subclass by hand.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I'll check those out.  This is within the context of an ATL project, so that's why I was looking at `CThreadPool`.

Comment: use use system pool and `QueueUserWorkItem` or  `CreateThreadpoolWork`